Integrals of vector spherical harmonics
I am trying to prove the integral relations of the vector spherical harmonics as defined by Barrera et al, 1985, and which are listed on the wiki page: here. In particular, define a VSH as,
$$
\boldsymbol{\Phi}_l^m := \mathbf{r} \times \nabla Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
Then according to Eq. 3.21 of Barrera et al, 1985, the following identity holds:
$$
\int d\Omega \boldsymbol{\Phi}_l^m \cdot \boldsymbol{\Phi}_{l'}^{m',*} = l(l+1) \delta_{ll'} \delta_{mm'}
$$
I am trying to prove this identity without much luck. Expanding the left hand side gives,
$$
\int d\Omega \boldsymbol{\Phi}_l^m \cdot \boldsymbol{\Phi}_{l'}^{m',*} = \int d\Omega \frac{mm'}{\sin^2{\theta}} Y_l^m Y_{l'}^{m',*} + \partial_{\theta} Y_l^m \partial_{\theta} Y_{l'}^{m',*}
$$
but it is not obvious how to tackle these integrals.
As an extension to this question, I would really like to solve the integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} d\theta \sin{\theta} \boldsymbol{\Phi}_l^m \cdot \boldsymbol{\Phi}_{l'}^{m',*}
$$
(e.g. integrate only over a partial colatitude range instead of the whole sphere).
Does anyone have suggestions how to make progress on these integrals?

The orbital angular momentum operator in natural units ($\hbar=1$) is
$$\mathbf L=-i\,(\boldsymbol r\times\boldsymbol\nabla)=\mathrm L_x\boldsymbol i+\mathrm L_y\boldsymbol j+\mathrm L_z\boldsymbol k$$
The main property of this operator is
$$\mathbf L^2Y_{\ell m}=\ell(\ell+1)Y_{\ell m}$$
We can also define the operators
$$\mathrm L_+=\mathrm L_x+i\mathrm L_y\qquad \& \qquad \mathrm L_-=\mathrm L_x-i\mathrm L_y$$
and so
$$\mathbf L=\dfrac{\mathrm L_+ + \mathrm L_-}{2}\boldsymbol i+\dfrac{\mathrm L_+ - \mathrm L_-}{2i}\boldsymbol j+\mathrm L_z\boldsymbol k$$
Your vector spherical harmonic is thus defined as
$$\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}=i\mathbf LY_{\ell m}$$
Thereafter, the inner product of this VHS yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega&=\int (-i\mathbf L^{\ast}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast})\cdot(i\mathbf LY_{\ell m})\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&=\int\left[\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathrm L_+^{\ast}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast})(\mathrm L_+Y_{\ell m})+\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathrm L_-^{\ast}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast})(\mathrm L_-Y_{\ell m})+(\mathrm L_z^{\ast}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast})(\mathrm L_zY_{\ell m})\right]\,\mathrm d\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\langle \mathrm L_i\phi|\psi\rangle=\langle \mathrm \phi|\mathrm L_i\psi\rangle$ for any $i=\{x,y,z\}$, then $\langle \mathrm L_+\phi|\psi\rangle=\langle \mathrm \phi|\mathrm L_-\psi\rangle$ and $\langle \mathrm L_-\phi|\psi\rangle=\langle \mathrm \phi|\mathrm L_+\psi\rangle$. Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}\cdot \boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\,\mathrm d\Omega&=\int\left[\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathrm L_+^{\ast}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast})(\mathrm L_+Y_{\ell m})+\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathrm L_-^{\ast}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast})(\mathrm L_-Y_{\ell m})+(\mathrm L_z^{\ast}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast})(\mathrm L_zY_{\ell m})\right]\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&=\int \left[\dfrac{1}{2}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\,(\mathrm L_-\mathrm L_+Y_{\ell m})+\dfrac{1}{2}Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\,(\mathrm L_+\mathrm L_-Y_{\ell m})+Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}(\mathrm L_z^2Y_{\ell m})\right]\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&=\int Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\left[\dfrac{1}{2}\,\mathrm L_-\mathrm L_++\dfrac{1}{2}\,\mathrm L_+\mathrm L_-+\mathrm L_z^2\right]Y_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&=\int Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\,\mathbf L^2Y_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&=\ell(\ell+1)\int Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}Y_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&=\ell(\ell+1)\delta_{\ell\ell'}\delta_{mm'}\ \square
\end{aligned}
$$
All of this was derivated thanks to Joe Shapiro's lecture notes on Electricity and Magnetism and this other PSE post. It is true that we could've concluded the same quicker by using the hermiticity of $L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$ instead of using these $L_+$, $L_-$ and $L_z$ operators, but oh well... I did not intend to make this answer longer but to complete the derivation it'd be nice to proof the orthogonality of spherical harmonics and the hermiticity of these operators.
As for your integral,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega,$$
from the last step you can easily infere
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega=\ell(\ell+1)\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}Y_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega$$

$\mathbf{Alternative\ proof\ due\ to\ Barrera's:}$ According to Barrera,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}&=(\boldsymbol r\times\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell' m'})\cdot(\boldsymbol r\times\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell m})\\
&=\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot[(\boldsymbol r\times\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell m})\times\boldsymbol r]\\
&=\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot[r^2\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell m}-\boldsymbol r(\boldsymbol r\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell m})]
\end{aligned}
$$
Moreover since $Y_{\ell m}$ depends on $\theta$ and $\phi$, then its gradient has no $\hat{\boldsymbol r}$ component and thus $\boldsymbol r\cdot \boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell m}=0$ and so
$$\boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}=r^2\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell m}=\boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell m}$$
Furthermore,
$$r^2\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell m}=r^2\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]-Y_{\ell m}r^2\boldsymbol\nabla^2Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}$$
Therefore,
$$\int \boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega=\int r^2\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm d\Omega-\int Y_{\ell m}r^2\boldsymbol\nabla^2Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}\,\mathrm d\Omega$$
The first integral can be proven to vanish whereas the second integral is just
$$-\ell'(\ell'+1)\int Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}Y_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega=-\ell'(\ell'+1)\delta_{\ell\ell'}\delta_{mm'}$$
due to $r^2\boldsymbol\nabla^2Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}=-\ell'(\ell'+1)Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}$. In summary,
$$\int \boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega=\int \boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Phi_{\ell m}\,\mathrm d\Omega=\ell'(\ell'+1)\delta_{\ell\ell'}\delta_{mm'}$$

To prove
$$\int r^2\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm d\Omega=0$$
We'll exploit
$$\int_{r\leq R} \boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[\Theta(a-r)Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm dV$$
where $\Theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside function.
By the divergence theorem, this is equal to
$$\oint_{r=R} \Theta(a-r)Y_{\ell m}\underbrace{\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol r}}_0\,\mathrm dS=0$$
Moreover, if we develop the product rule for the original volume integral we'll have
$$\small\int_{r\leq R} \boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[\Theta(a-r)Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm dV=\int_{r\leq R} \Theta(a-r)\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm dV+\underbrace{\int_{r\leq R} \underbrace{\boldsymbol\nabla[\Theta(a-r)]}_{-\delta(a-r)\hat{\boldsymbol r}}\cdot Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}\,\mathrm dV}_0$$
Finally, we know $\mathrm dV=r^2\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\Omega$ so it follows that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{r\leq R} \boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[\Theta(a-r)Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm dV=0&=\int_0^{R>a} r^2\Theta(a-r)\,\mathrm dr\,\int\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&=\dfrac{a^3}{3}\int\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
&\Longrightarrow \int\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot[Y_{\ell m}\boldsymbol\nabla Y_{\ell'm'}^{\ast}]\,\mathrm d\Omega=0\enspace \square
\end{aligned}
$$

The relation $\langle \mathrm L_+\phi|\psi\rangle=\langle \mathrm \phi|\mathrm L_-\psi\rangle$ may not hold over a subset of the sphere, so I'm not sure if the last equation is correct.

You're right, in that case best option would be to use the expression you got that includes the $\partial_\theta Y_{\ell m}$ terms and then use
$$Y_{\ell m}=\mathcal N_{\ell m}P_{\ell m}(\cos\theta)\exp(im\phi)$$
plus the recurrence relation for $\partial_\theta P_{\ell m}(\cos\theta)$ which can be found here in eq. $(8)$.

I also thought about proving the orthogonality for $\boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell m}$ but couldn't go any further, any ideas? Basically
$$\int\boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\cdot \boldsymbol\Psi_{\ell m},\mathrm d\Omega=\int r^2\nabla Y_{\ell m}\cdot\nabla Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast},\mathrm d\Omega$$
where
$$\nabla Y_{\ell m}\cdot\nabla Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}=\nabla(Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\nabla Y_{\ell m})-Y_{\ell' m'}^{\ast}\nabla^2 Y_{\ell m}$$

The appendix of Carrascal et al, 1991 "Vector spherical harmonics and their application to classical electrodynamics", proves that $\int \boldsymbol{\Psi}_{l'}^{m',} \cdot \boldsymbol{\Psi}l^m d\Omega = \int \boldsymbol{\Phi}{l'}^{m',} \cdot \boldsymbol{\Phi}_l^m d\Omega$, using a much different approach than the $L$ operators you used here.

It looks as though he approached the integral using the same calculus vector identity as me. Furthermore he shows that the integral of the first term vanishes. I'll have a look at that.
